# Using UICollectionViewCell with IBOutlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I wonder if it is possible to use UICollectionViewCell with IBOutlet? As I always get this error

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the cell returned from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: was not retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: at index path

Below is my code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *cellArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionViewCell *sort1Cell;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionViewCell *sort2Cell;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionViewCell *sort3Cell;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionViewCell *sort4Cell;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.cellArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [cellArray addObject:sort1Cell];
    [cellArray addObject:sort2Cell];
    [cellArray addObject:sort3Cell];
    [cellArray addObject:sort4Cell];
    [theCollectionView reloadData];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;  //THE ERROR IS FROM HERE
}
```

Or perhaps I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if it is possible to use UICollectionViewCell with IBOutlet

No, it isn't possible. (And even if it is, don't do it.) Cells are *reused*; they have no permanent existence within the collection view. You never know what cell object will be used at a given section/item position. Therefore you must *dequeue* the cell every time `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is called.

There are ways to obtain a reference to a cell that actually exists within the collection view, at runtime. (Though in many case, the need to do even this is to be regarded as a Bad Smell.)

Comment: Thanks for firm answer, matt

I'm just trying to display 4 static buttons. Each with different width, and I want it to fill horizontal space first, then move to next row if it is full. Thats why I want to use UICollectionView

This could be done with UITableView without error, but it can't fill horizontal space

Comment: I didn't say you can't use UICollectionView. I said you can't statically get the cells by way of an IBOutlet. And you did not ask whether there is another way to lay out the buttons in the way you describe. I answered the question you actually asked.